# Setting custom path for sqlite db in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, sqlite

I want to use the sqlite db stored in "C:\Folder\my_database.sqlite" , what should i do? I want to use that sqlite db. Can anyone please suggest me a solution?﻿

So i can give the path to sqlite in database.php below:

```
 'sqlite' => [
            'driver' => 'sqlite',
            'database' => "path to my sqlite db",
            'prefix' => '',
        ],
```

Also if that is done, then i can change my default connection to sqlite. Like:

```
DB::setDefaultConnection('sqlite');
```

Can anyone please suggest me a solution?﻿

Comment: Not exactly sure what the problem is, but have you tried replacing `"path to my sqlite db"` with `"C:\Folder\my_database.sqlite"` in that code?

Comment: 'database' => env('DB_DATABASE_LITE', "C:\Folder\my_database.sqlite"),

Will this work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the [Laravel Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/database) states:

> After creating a new SQLite database using a command such as  touch
>   database/database.sqlite, you can easily configure your environment
>   variables to point to this newly created database by using the
>   **database's absolute path**:

```
 'sqlite' => [
            'driver' => 'sqlite',
            'database' => "C:\Folder\my_database.sqlite",
            'prefix' => '',
        ],
```

To make it the default connection, just set this in your .env file:

```
DB_CONNECTION=sqlite
```

Answer (score 2):

Open your .env file and set,

```
DB_CONNECTION=sqlite
DB_DATABASE=C:\Folder\my_database.sqlite
```

further more information you can see: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/database

Answer (score 1):

for set sqlite database you can add absoulate path like this in `database.php` file..

```
'sqlite' => [
        'driver' => 'sqlite',
        'database' =>  'C:\Folder\my_database.sqlite',
        'prefix' => '',
],
```

for set a default sqlite connection  update this in your `.env` file:

```
DB_CONNECTION=sqlite
```

for production update line(number 16) in `database.php`

```
'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'sqlite'),
```

and then run this command in terminal for **remove old configration** and `create new configration` file.

```
php artisan config:cache
```